# Byte array argument null in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new to android and i do some research about the `viewpager`, `activity`, and `fragment` but my problem is after i captured the photo the image didn't show in the `layout`.

Here is the code where i capture the photo:

```
public class MainStepView extends AppCompatActivity {

private StepperIndicator indicator;
private FloatingActionButton fabCapture;

@Override
protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stepview_main);
    setTitle("New Customer");

    indicator = (StepperIndicator) findViewById(R.id.stepper_indicator);
    fabCapture = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabCamera);

    final ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    indicator.setViewPager(pager, true);
    indicator.addOnStepClickListener(new StepperIndicator.OnStepClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStepClicked(int step) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(step, true);
        }
    });


    fabCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, indicator.getCurrentStep());
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == 3){
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream);
            byte[] byteArray = bStream.toByteArray();
            ClientIdFragment fragment = new ClientIdFragment();
            bundle.putByteArray("image", byteArray);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code where the image should be displayed

```
public class ClientIdFragment extends Fragment {

ImageView ivClientId;
FloatingActionButton fabCapture;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stepview_client_id, container, false);
    Bitmap bmp;
    ivClientId = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivClientId);
    fabCapture = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fabCamera);

    byte[] byteArray = null;
    if (byteArray != null && byteArray.length > 0){
    byteArray =  getActivity().getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    ivClientId.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ivClientId = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivClientId);
} 
}
```

Here is where i display the different layouts:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   switch (position){
       case 0: return new ClientInfoFragment();
       case 1: return new ClientAddressFragment();
       case 2: return new ClientOtherFragment();
       case 3: return new ClientIdFragment();
       case 4: return new ClientSelfieFragment();
       case 5: return new ClientWithIdFragment();
       case 6: return new ClientSignatureFragment();
       default : return new ClientSummaryFragment();
   }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 9;
}
}
```

Here is my scenario: I have 7 layout called by `viewpager` using `stepperindicator` before i capture photo i go to layout where the image will be display and initiate the `fab` then after i take photo image has not been displayed in the layout

Note: the image has been save in the gallery. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the byte array out of the `Activity`'s `Intent`'s arguments:

```java
byteArray =  getActivity().getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
```

but it's stored in the `Fragment`'s arguments.  You should do:

```java
byteArray = getArguments().getByteArray("image");
```

Additionally, you're only retrieving it in a conditional that's always false:

```java
byte[] byteArray = null;
if (byteArray != null && byteArray.length > 0){
```

byteArray is always going to be null, because you just set it to null.  You probably meant to check that after reading it.

This whole block should probably be:

```java
byte[] byteArray = getArguments().getByteArray("image");
if (byteArray != null && byteArray.length > 0){
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    ivClientId.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Last but not least, you're throwing away the Fragment without adding it, then creating another one without arguments in your `PagerAdapter`.  You need to set the arguments on *that* instance.

Comment: The image didn't show in layout. Maybe there is something wrong in my `PagerAdapter`?

Comment: I just noticed another bug, updated the answer - hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: When it tried the code it says `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Can you show your actual code?  The code you pasted clearly isn't it, because you never add the `ClientIdFragment`, so it couldn't be called.

Comment: Actually it was my actual code, before i reached step 3. I get the error

Comment: aaaaand your added code explains it, now that you've shown how you actually create the Fragment.  You're not setting the arguments.  You're creating a Fragment and throwing it away in onActivityResult, and then creating a totally different Fragment with no arguments in your PagerAdapter.

Comment: Can you help me? I am new to android. I dont have any idea how it works

Comment: Sorry, I've told you what the problems are (3 so far) and how to solve them (two with code, one with a general description).  I've edited the answer to include the third problem.  I can't rearchitect your app for you, but hopefully this guides you in the right direction (look into how you might get the Bitmap data into your PagerAdapter).  Please upvote and/or accept the answer if it was helpful, and good luck!